# 4G Router used in IoT application losing WiFi connection at specific time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am currently testing out a prototype of a new IoT product in two separate office environments. The prototypes consists of a Adafruit Feather Huzzah (ESP8266) microcontroller along with some sensors. At certain time intervals and at certain triggers in the sensor input, the microcontroller sends a small data package to a remote server which I can access. At times it also downloads and flashes new code versions which I have uploadet to the server.

All of this works on a small scale (3-4 devices) in the workshop where I've created them. The problem occurs now that I'm testing the devices using SIM-driven 4G WiFi Routers at two companies.

I am using a D-Link DWR-921 (http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dwr-921-4g-lte-router). Altogether I have 25 devices connected to 3 different routers in the same room. All routers use channel 12 but have different SSIDs. I am doing a similar test at another company.

Everything worked fine for a day or so before all devices lost connection at approximately the same time, 11.30 AM, *regardless of which company the device is placed at*. This time is not the same each day, but when connection is lost, it is always at a specific time for **all** devices. Apparently, restarting the routers didn't help. Some of the devices seem to regain connection at some point during the following night, but the number of devices able to regain connection gets smaller each day.

I am have no idea what is causing the disconnect as I have no access to any kind of system log for the connection - I can only see at what times the devices start and stop sending. The routers are running the latest firmware and the SIM cards still have data available.
Do you have any suggestions as to what MIGHT cause the simultaneous disconnect and how to fix it?

Comment: You're essentially asking people to diagnose an issue with devices running custom software, without providing access to this software.

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with a similar issue and found two culprits.  Parts of our Wi-Fi network would have connection issues each morning.  It was always one or two APs using 2.4GHz

Much time making physical changes(cables, location of AP, etc) and looking for hardware errors in logs.

After a number of site surveys, we found a neighbor in our complex arrived at approximately the same time each day and turned on his wireless router.  He turned it off when out of office to keep people from using his bandwidth.  In addition he had added a high gain antenna so signal would reach the back of his warehouse. When chatting with him we mentioned adding some security to his router would keep people from accessing when he was out of the office.

Once we changed channel we had no issues with our AP until two new networks appeared with other neighbors in the complex. A move to all 5GHz devices has resolved the issue at the moment.

In the second case it was an office in a larger building.  The single AP would go off line at around the same time some days.  As the office only had a few users and most were wired clients it was often unreported.

While working on other tasks we noticed a UPS on a workstation beeping for a moment.  Users reported it did that often in the morning.  A review of UPS logs on the server showed no power issues.  Workstation was connected to a SmartUPS and monitoring enabled.  A week of monitoring showed a large power dip almost every morning.  AP was then connected to a UPS and that circuit had same power issue.

In our case restarting the AP resolved issue right away.  Landlord's electrician found issues on several circuits and provided repairs.

UPS was still used on AP.

Comment: Congratulations, and welcome to Super User's Steward × 6 club.